# Styling QPushButton with CSS?

Tags: css, qt, button, pyqt4

I'm trying to create a `QPushButton` that's just got an icon and a **constant** background color.
So that I can swap out the icon when the user clicks it, without any other apparent effects (this is for a roll-up/roll-down feature).  I've added an entry like this to my stylesheet:

```
QPushButton.ToggleButton {
    background-color: #8af; 
}
```

and set the button's class to match, and this does indeed give me the look I want, except that when I click on it the background color changes to a lighter blue, which I don't want.  What am I missing?

Edit: I guess I should mention I'm using Qt 4.5 and PyQt 4.6 to do this...

Comment: You need to set the style for the :pressed pseudo-state as well: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton

Comment: Tried that a couple of ways and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I know people like using stylesheets, but in this situation I think it is just as easy to make a custom button.  Define a class that inherits from `QAbstractButton`, and override the paint() method.  In the paint method, fill the rect with your desired background color, and then paint the current icon on top.  It might be slightly more complicated if you want the border around the button as well, but not a lot.

Alternately, you could also look at the roles for `QPalette`, specifically `QPalette::Light` and `QPalette::Midlight`, which might be used to adjust the color of the button when pressed.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

Try giving the button an ID with QObject::setObjectName and then applying the style with #idSelector?

In Python the code would probably look something like this:

```
button = QPushButton(self)
button.setObjectName("ToggleButton")
```

and stylesheet like this:

```
#ToggleButton:pressed {
  background-color: #8af;
}
```

## Further reading

- The [QFriendFeed example application](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/53e6216b-4655-4280-a00d-a1d110fa2e99/Qt_for_S60_QFriendFeed_Example.html) at [Forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/) is using Qt style sheets heavily to customize the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing doing `background-color: #8af !important;` would be too obvious so I'm assuming that doesn't work. It's worth a try if you haven't done it yet.

Otherwise, as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531062/how-to-change-a-qpushbutton-icon-when-it-has-focus), there are specific states you can style. Try setting the same background color for the pressed state:

```
QPushButton.ToggleButton:pressed { background-color: #8af; }
```

Sorry if I misunderstood. Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried setting the pressed pseudo state, and no dice.  Tried setting it with it sharing a definition with QPushButton.ToggleButton and by itself too...

Comment: adding the !important doesn't seem to do it either.  The button is sitting on top of a frame that's dark blue (the color I want to match), which is sitting on top of a lighter blue frame, and it seems to be that color that's coming through when I click it...

Comment: Perhaps my syntax is incorrect, try QPushButton:pressed.ToggleButton

Comment: Is the color staying changed after having clicked it? Then also try setting it for the :focus state. Try both methods of declaration since I'm not so sure which one's correct :/

Comment: It's not, it just changes to the light blue while I'm clicking it then changes back.

Answer (score 0):

open the button's stylesheet in Qt designer and try this:
`QPushButton:pressed {
         image: url(/path/to/your/file/fileName.png);
     }`